# How to prove this (geometrically correct) inequality?

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1, x_1^*\in \left[0,a\right]$ and $x_2, x_2^*\in \left[0,b\right]$ where $a, b \in \left(0,1\right)$ and $a<b$.

Suppose
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x_1}{x_2}>\frac{a}{b}
\end{equation*} and
\begin{equation*}\frac{x_1^*}{x_2^*}<\frac{a}{b}.
\end{equation*}

I want to prove
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a-x_1^*}{b-x_2^*}>\frac{a-x_1}{b-x_2}.
\end{equation*} I believe this inequality is correct based on the following graph.
[image]

The first inequality implies the red point is below the dashed line and the second inequality implies the blue point is above the dashed line. Then the third inequality is implied by the fact that the blue line is flatter than the red line.

But I had difficulty in proving it:

\begin{equation*}
\left(a-x_1^*\right)\left(b-x_2\right)-\left(a-x_1\right)\left(b-x_2^*\right)=\left(a x_2^*-bx_1^*\right)+\left(bx_1-ax_2\right)+\left(x_1^* x_2-x_1 x_2^*\right).
\end{equation*} On the right hand side, the first and second terms are positive, but the third term is negative, so I failed to prove the whole thing is positive.

I had a vague feeling that this inequality has the flavour of "solution inequality": the density of the mixed solution is between the two original densities.

Comment: It will be much easier to **visualize** when we rename the variables to $x_1,x_2 \in [0,a]$ & $y_1,y_2 \in [0,b]$ & then use the slopes of the lines involved.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to prove independently that (as suggested by your picture)
$$\frac{a-x_1}{b-x_2}<\frac ab$$
and
$$\frac{a-x_1^*}{b-x_2^*}>\frac ab.$$
For instance for the first one:
$$(a-x_1)b<(b-x_2)a$$
because
$$x_1b>x_2a.$$

Answer (score 0):

By the [mediant inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Properties),

- $\dfrac ab = \dfrac{(a-x_1)+x_1}{(b-x_2)+x_2}$ is between $\dfrac{a-x_1}{b-x_2}$ and $\dfrac{x_1}{x_2}$. Given $\dfrac ab < \dfrac{x_1}{x_2}$, so
  $$ \frac{a-x_1}{b-x_2} < \frac{(a-x_1)+x_1}{(b-x_2)+x_2} < \frac{x_1}{x_2}$$
- $\dfrac ab = \dfrac{(a-x_1^*)+x_1^*}{(b-x_2^*)+x_2^*}$ is between $\dfrac{a-x_1^*}{b-x_2^*}$ and $\dfrac{x_1^*}{x_2^*}$. Given $\dfrac{x_1^*}{x_2^*} < \dfrac ab$, so
  $$\frac{x_1^*}{x_2^*} < \frac{(a-x_1^*)+x_1^*}{(b-x_2^*)+x_2^*} < \frac{a-x_1^*}{b-x_2^*}$$

Combining the two inequalities,

$$\frac{a-x_1}{b-x_2} < \frac ab < \frac{a-x_1^*}{b-x_2^*}$$

(This skips the cases where $x_1^* = 0$ or $x_1 = a$)